# What is Btrfs's disk space caching?

Tags: btrfs, hard-drive-cache

I noticed in my syslog that BTRFS reports enabling "disk space caching". What is Btrfs's "disk space caching"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This space_cache option will be selected while mounting a mount point which has Btrfs file system. This will store the free space cache on the disk to make the caching of a block much faster. Without this, Btrfs has to scan the entire tree every time looking for the free space that can be allocated.

Comment: Nicely ripped almost directly from a [phoronix report](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=btrfs_space_cache).

Answer (score 7):

Short and to the point:

if enabled, Kernel will have available FS free space block addresses in memory, thus when you create a new file it will immediately start writing data to disk.

More details:

the mount option `space_cache` now is the default on recent kernels. It provides better performance, when creating new files or writing new data to disk. Please see link. You can disable it by adding `nospace_cache` mount option.

[nospace_cache since: 3.2, space_cache=v1 and space_cache=v2 since 4.5, default: space_cache=v1](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs(5))